# Typescript error "x" is not a module

Tags: angularjs, typescript, pixi.js

I'm building an app with PixiJs and Angular2 and I'm trying to import the pixi typescript definitions (https://github.com/pixijs/pixi-typescript).

I want to extend the Pixi `Sprite` type, but I am unable to import the library.

Here is the code:

```
import { Sprite } from '../../assets/pixi.js';

export class test extends Sprite {
     //...
}
```

This results in the error `"File 'C:.../src/assets/pixi.js.d.ts' is not a module. at line 1 col 24"`

The path is definitiely correct. What am I doing wrong and how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason for PixiJS being in an `assets` directory? Why not use NPM: `npm install --save-dev pixi.js @types/pixi.js`?

Comment: How would I import pixi in that case?

Comment: `import { Sprite } from "pixi.js"` etc. NPM-installed modules are imported/required using the name of the module.

Comment: Is there any way to import the entire library into my angular 2 application? Or do I need to import types as I need them? For example, in `app.module.ts`, using `import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js'` and then being able to use the variable `PIXI` everywhere?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#import